# how can i using CPU8085 and PIO8155 crate an alarm circuit and program

Tags: cpu, hobbyist, smoke-sensor

example ; we have smoke sensor, speaker and my circuit.When Sensor has been active, speaker to sing it. i'm newbie in this topic. how can i do it like this circuit ?

Comment: Explain yourself a bit better...

Comment: shortly; my homework is CPU8085 and PIO8155 comprising an alarm circuit

Comment: We don't do homework here.  If you need help please explain a specific electronics problem, demonstrate what you have tried already and outline what existing knowledge and experience you have (perhaps in your profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make an exception to the no-homework rule.

1) Configure the 8155 to have both inputs and outputs.

2) Connect the smoke detector output to an 8155 input.

3) Connect the speaker to an 8155 output.

4) Monitor the input port, and if the smoke detector is active, drive the speaker output with a square wave at some convenient frequency.

That's it. And no, you don't get any details. That's for you to study on. The 8085 and 8155 data sheets have all the information you need. Step 4 is software, so you need to pay attention to the 8085 instruction set, which is part of the 8085 data sheet.

Lots of luck. Work hard.

Comment: Don't forget adding some RAM and ROM, as well as the glue logic to interface the whole caboodle to the address and data buses.

Comment: At the risk of muddying the waters, all he needs is an 8155 and a PROM. Mapping the 8155 as I/O and the PROM as memory, no glue logic is required. For what he's doing, no external RAM is required. Registers in the 8085 are enough.

Comment: Yes, that's doable like that. But you want to make a *proper* system don't you? ;)

Comment: @Majenko - where's the fun in that? Minimal systems... aaah, I've seen a similar era (1980s) embedded Z80 system that kept its stack in ROM ... no RAM needed! and another one that ran out of registers so it used the DRAM refresh counter too...

Comment: @BrianDrummond I guess you could even, if you're not using all of it, use some of the 8155's internal registers for data storage...